# Modifying button properties - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

What I am trying to achieve is, when the user recognised in the table with week 1 "found", the button should turn red,  disable functionality and change the button content. However an error message comes up as soon as I enter the screen saying:

> "fatal error encountered during command execution".

If anyone could possibly help I would much appreciate it in advance :)

```
Private Sub LondonC_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
    Try
        Dim connStr As String = ""
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select week1 from table where username= @name AND week1 = 'found'"
        Dim username = Login.txtusername.Text
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        If (READER.Read() = True) Then
            Query = "select * from table where username='" & Login.txtusername.Text & "'"
            Dim week1 As String
            week1 = READER("week1")
            Button4.BackColor = Color.Red
            Button4.Enabled = False
            Button4.Text = "Completed"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it `Windows Form`? And in which line does the error occur?

Comment: where is value for @name in your code ?
also no connection strings ..

Comment: Forgot to add the parameter to the MySqlCommand, the second Query has no meaning at all. Check previous answer.

Comment: @Steve I always greatly appreciate the help man! I will try fixing it, if i struggle i may need your help

Comment: steve i added the add parameter to mysqlcommand and removed the second query.. how now recieve a message stating "good job @ahmet however now i receive a message saying "unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'" any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You defined username string variable but forgot to add username parameter in your query.

Add this lines to your code:

```
Dim username = Login.txtusername.Text
Query = Query.Replace("@name", username)
```

Comment: good job @ahmet however now i receive a message saying "unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'

Comment: OMG So much effort to teach how to use parameters and you destroy everything in two lines.  @mr-c then you don't have a column named username, check your table on the database.

Comment: @Steve i was being so dumb, i don't need this but... "COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username" and it fixed! Thanks soooo much! you're a life saver ahha :P

Comment: @steve Is there any way, after the user finds the item, changes the value in the database "found" .. that you can automatically refresh the button and then the button properties change. I tried " Dim Episodes = New Episodes". However no luck. Thanks